# Bootstrap responsive issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap button with class "navbar-toggle" in navbar appears when screen less 768px, i.e. 767px. But but ipad mini has screen with dimensions 768-1024px.
Should i override bootstrap style from 768px to 992px, like this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the bootstrap file itself, but it would be advised if you really need to do this to add the extra dimensions to your own custom css file which will over-write the bootstrap lib file.

Its perfectly ok to overwrite bootstrap but personally i would specify the MIN and MAX width to ensure you are catering for that particular edge case.

Answer (score -1):

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

At bottom of the page you can see classes like .visible-phone, .visible-tablet, .visible-desktop and their behavior at some sizes.

Comment: Than change your tag to bootstrap3 or twitter-bootstrap3. I dont have magic ball to see what are you using!

Comment: ReadyToWork, then you have to buy it